# Is my StackExchange-Description written correctly?

Tags: commas, orthography, subordinate-clauses, which-that, non-restrictive

This is my profile-description of the StackExchange-Site:

> "Dösbaddel" is a (North-)German word for "Dummkopf" which probably means "fool" in English.

Is it written properly or do I need to insert a comma right after "Dummkopf"?

> "Dösbaddel" is a (North-)German word for "Dummkopf"`,` which probably means "fool" in English.

If you find more things one could/should change, I would be glad if you would inform me about that.

Comment: Probably, considering you posted this question here. Please re-read the Tour, and the Help on what kind of questions are acceptable here.

Comment: *Dummkopf* is actually in English dictionaries, defined as a stupid person or blockhead, so not the same thing as a fool though obviously there's overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your subordinate clause following *which* is here an “optional” non-restrictive clause rather the type of “required” restrictive clause which I have just now used here, the orthographic convention in standard written English is to always use a comma.

This is quite different from the standard orthographic conventions of written German. In German, you’ve been trained to put a comma before subordinators like *das* even when these are used restrictively. So where in English we might write:

- This is the house that Jack built.

In German you would need an obligatory comma there:

- Dies ist das Haus`,` das Jach gebaut hat.

We don’t do that for restrictive subordinate clauses in English, so you have probably gotten used to not doing so in English.

But there’s a different convention in play here for English. When your subordinate clause is merely adding optional information, the clause is considered non-restrictive. You can delete it without changing the overall meaning of the sentence. This kind of clause we do indeed precede with a comma in English. This strategy allows us to to distinguish these two very different statements:

1. This is Jack’s house, which I have never seen before now.
2. This is Jack’s house that I have never seen before now.

The first sentence says it’s Jack’s house — then, almost as a parenthetical aside, mentions that you haven’t seen it before now. You could have used a dash there instead of a comma, even, although this is more abrupt. Both represent an actual change in the cadence of the phrase, a little “pause” if you would. It is not a “silent” comma; it can be heard in speech.

The second sentence suggests that Jack has other houses besides this one, ones which you *have* seen previously. If you deleted the clause, you would lose that meaning.

Because your cited sentence is only adding descriptive information rather than restricting exactly which particular *Dummkopf* it is that you mean, it should take a written comma.

Comment: I'd think most would use brackets for a total aside (ie we've not already been discussing  translations ...) here.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations! I think that with your information I can apply this to similar problems with setting commas.